# Operator Panel, values/tweek options don't show up

Tags: operator, panel

some issue is bothering me for a while now. I could manage to work around it but i realise that I'm missing some options.

What I usually see in tutorials is that the options/values of a specific options, lets say, the bevel tool in edit mode (ctrl+b), will show op in the operator field.

Most of the tools I execute, the tweakable values/options, don't show up, or in the bar below:

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzS1A.jpg)

Comment: The values in the header tells you that the operator isn't finished yet. You will usually see the Last Operator panel content after finishing the operator. So do as adviced in the header: Confirm with Enter/LMB. And you should see the Last Operator content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your image it shows that the operator panel is minimised. Click the arrow next to "Operator" to maximise it and show the options.

Answer (score 3):

Operator options show up in the *Redo Panel* *after* the operator has been executed.

If the operator is cancelled instead of confirmed, no options will appear as no operator has been run (even though an operator was *started*).

Your screenshot shows the operator is *running*, but not yet *finished/confirmed*.

Comment: This made my day. Searched for the panel like crazy :-)